# Один обработчик формы на AJAX для множества форм

Tags: phpmyadmin, ajax, javascript, php

Суть такова: Нужен обработчик, который будит обрабатывать форму со страницы содержащую множество одинаковых форм, у которых разные id.

///PHP генерирует формы

```
printf ("
<li><a href='/goods/climate_technology/conditioners/goods.php?id=%s'><img src='%s' alt='%s' /><div id='divId-content'>
<h3>%s</h3></a>                                                                 <p>Мощность охлажд., кВт <span>%s</span></p>                                                                <p>Мощность обогр., кВт <span>%s</span></p>                                                         <p id='characteristic-cash'><strong>Цена: </strong><q>%s<span> грн</span></q></p>                                                               <div id='complete-description'><a href='/goods/climate_technology/conditioners/goods.php?id=%s'>Полное описание</a></div>                                                               <div id='button-order'><a class='modalbox' href='#inline_%s'>Заказать</a></div>                                                                                                                             <div id='inline_%s' style='display: none;'>                                                                 <h2>Отправка сообщения</h2>
<form id='contact_%s' name='contact' action='#' method='post'>
<label for='email'>Ваш E-mail</label>
<input type='email' id='email' name='email' class='txt'>                                                                    <br>                                                                        <label for='msg'>Введите сообщение</label>
<textarea id='msg' name='msg' class='txtarea'></textarea>
<button id='send'>Отправить E-mail</button>
</form>
</li>",$myrow["id"],$myrow["URL_img"],$myrow["name"],$myrow["abbreviation"],$myrow["cooling_capacity"],$myrow["heating_power"],get_sum($price,$myrow["price"]),$myrow["id"],$myrow["id"],$myrow["id"],$myrow["id"]);
}
while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array ($result));
```

/// JS скрипт который проверяет форму и отправляет в обработчик

```
function validateEmail(email) { 
var reg = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return reg.test(email);
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".modalbox").fancybox();
    $("#contact").submit(function() { return false; });

    $("#send").on("click", function(){
    var emailval  = $("#email").val();
    var msgval    = $("#msg").val();
    var msglen    = msgval.length;
    var mailvalid = validateEmail(emailval);

    if(mailvalid == false) {
        $("#email").addClass("error");
    }
    else if(mailvalid == true){
    $("#email").removeClass("error");
    }

    if(msglen < 4) {
        $("#msg").addClass("error");
    }
    else if(msglen >= 4){
    $("#msg").removeClass("error");
    }

    if(mailvalid == true && msglen >= 4) {
    // если обе проверки пройдены
    // сначала мы скрываем кнопку отправки
    $("#send").replaceWith("<em>отправка...</em>");

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'sendmessage.php',
        data: $("#contact").serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
        if(data == "true") {
        $("#contact").fadeOut("fast", function(){
        $(this).before("<p><strong>”спешно! ¬аше сообщение отправлено  :)</strong></p>");
        setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 1000);
        });
        }
        }
        });
        }
        });
        });
```

Для подробного разбора могу выслать файлы.

Answer (score 1):

[Используй плагин для jquery - jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org)

> This jQuery plugin makes simple clientside form validation easy, whilst still offering plenty of customization options. It makes a good choice if you’re building something new from scratch, but also when you’re trying to integrate something into an existing application with lots of existing markup. The plugin comes bundled with a useful set of validation methods, including URL and email validation, while providing an API to write your own methods. All bundled methods come with default error messages in english and translations into 37 other languages.